# Windows Store Apps: Grid View Group Binding background color?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-store-apps

I have a grid view with a CollectionViewSource as it's items source.

I want to to bind the background property of each group container panel so that each group has its own background color.

how can this be achieved?

I'm trying to use binding in the `<GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>` of the gridview but can't  get it to work.

Comment: Many ways.  What have you done to achieve it?

Comment: Please check the updated question, I want to use binding in <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle> of the gridview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here's what I've got. I had to modify the **template** of the **Group Container Style**:

```
<GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="GroupItem">
                                <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,0,0,0" />
                                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="20"/>
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="GroupItem">
                                            <Border Background="{Binding Group, Converter={StaticResource ThemeColorConverter}}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                                                <Grid>
                                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                    <ContentControl x:Name="HeaderContent"
                                        Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                        ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                        ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplateSelector}"
                                        Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                        TabIndex="0"
                                        IsTabStop="False" />
                                                    <ItemsControl x:Name="ItemsControl"
                                      Grid.Row="1"
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding GroupItems}"
                                      IsTabStop="False"
                                      TabNavigation="Once"
                                      TabIndex="1" >
                                                        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerTransitions>
                                                            <TransitionCollection>
                                                                <AddDeleteThemeTransition />
                                                                <ContentThemeTransition />
                                                                <ReorderThemeTransition />
                                                                <EntranceThemeTransition IsStaggeringEnabled="False" />
                                                            </TransitionCollection>
                                                        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerTransitions>
                                                    </ItemsControl>
                                                </Grid>
                                            </Border>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
```

This line did the trick:

```
<Border Background="{Binding Group, Converter={StaticResource ColorConverter}}"/>
```

Binding to **Group** gives you access to the group's data source.

Answer (score 1):

Since the list will be grouped already, then applying a background on each `GridViewItem` will do the trick, depending on whether you want to define the `backgound` in each item as a property or use a converter to do that :

```
public class Data
{
    public String Prop1 { get; set; }
    public String Prop2 { get; set; }
    public SolidColorBrush GroupeBrush { get; set; } //the groupe background color
}
```

And the xaml,

```
<Page.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Name="DataCollection" IsSourceGrouped="true" />
</Page.Resources>

<Grid>
    <GridView SelectionMode="None"   ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource DataCollection}}" >
        <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Background="{Binding GroupeBrush}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Prop2}" />
                </Grid>                    
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
</Grid>
```

Or you could as well play around the `GridView` `GroupStyle` although you will need to find a way to bind the `background` from the `Style` `Setter`  :

```
<GridView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border Background="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <TextBlock Text='{Binding Key}' Foreground="White" Margin="5" Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}" />
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>

                <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="GroupItem">
                        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="600"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkGray"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3,0"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="BurlyWood"/>
                    </Style>
                </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>                   
            </GroupStyle>
        </GridView.GroupStyle>
```

Here the entire code behind in case any one wants to experiment more

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private ObservableCollection<Data> _datas = new ObservableCollection<Data>()
    {
        new Data()
        {
            Prop1 = "val1",
            Prop2 = "val2",
            GroupeBrush=new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue)
        }, new Data()
        {
            Prop1 = "val1",
            Prop2 = "val2",
            GroupeBrush=new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue)
        }, new Data()
        {
            Prop1 = "val1",
            Prop2 = "val3",
            GroupeBrush=new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue)
        }, new Data()
        {
            Prop1 = "val2",
            Prop2 = "val4",
            GroupeBrush=new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green)
        }, new Data()
        {   
            Prop1 = "val3",
            Prop2 = "val5",
            GroupeBrush=new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red)
        },
    };

    public ObservableCollection<Data> Datas
    {
        get
        {
            return _datas;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_datas == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _datas = value;                
        }
    }
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
        DataCollection.Source = GetAllGrouped();
    }
    public IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, Data>> GetAllGrouped()
    {
        return Datas.GroupBy(x => x.Prop1);
    }      
}

public class Data
{
    public String Prop1 { get; set; }
    public String Prop2 { get; set; }
    public SolidColorBrush GroupeBrush { get; set; } //the groupe background color
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that's a workaround that may not give the expected results. please check my answer